# Change class of div when typing in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the class of a div onkeypress and on onkeyup of a textarea. However only the text is changing inside the div not the class itself. I don't want the text inside the div to change just the class of the div.

https://jsfiddle.net/ud7op3kg/3/

JS

```
var timer = 0;

    function reduceTimer() {
      timer = timer - 1;
      isTyping(true);
    }

    function isTyping(val) {
      if (val == 'true') {
        document.getElementById('typing_on').innerHTML = "Class1";
      } else {

        if (timer <= 0) {
          document.getElementById('typing_on').innerHTML = "Class2";
        } else {
          setTimeout("reduceTimer();", 500);
        }
      }
    }
```

CSS

```
.class1 {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.class2 {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea onkeypress="isTyping('true'); timer=5;" onkeyup="isTyping('false')" name="textarea" cols="45" rows="5">
</textarea>
<div id="typing_on" class="class2">Class2</div>
```

Comment: change `innerHTML` with `className`

Comment: After applying this I also noticed after making this change I need to consider case sensitivity. Class1 in the js does not work, I have to match the case of my css which is class1. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('typing_on').innerHTML = "Class1";
```

This will change the innerHTML or content of the div. You need to give

```
document.getElementById('typing_on').className = "Class1";
```

Comment: use the .addClass() method if you want to retain the classes currently on the div. .removeClass() will remove a class in the same fashion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `+` selector to change style.

```
  #text:focus + #typing_on {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2k6pzy2y/

Comment: This is the solution I'd use if I just wanted to change the class on focus, thanks. However I specificially am looking to change the class when the textarea is being typed into

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
document.getElementById('typing_on').className = "Class1";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this very easily in jquery 
check https://jsfiddle.net/bullet/f4y4kskj/

```
    var timer = 0;

function reduceTimer() {
  timer = timer - 1;
  isTyping(true);
}

function isTyping(val) {
  if (val == 'true') {
    document.getElementById('typing_on').innerHTML = "Class1";
  } else {

    if (timer <= 0) {
      document.getElementById('typing_on').innerHTML = "Class2";
    } else {
      setTimeout("reduceTimer();", 500);
    }
  }
}

$("#textarea").keypress(function(evt) {
  isTyping('true')
  timer = 5;
  $("#typing_on").innerHTML = "Class1";
  $("#typing_on").removeClass("class2");
  $("#typing_on").addClass("class1");
  event.preventDefault();
});
$("#textarea").keyup(function(evt) {
  isTyping('true')
  $("#typing_on").innerHTML = "Class2";
  $("#typing_on").removeClass('class1');
  $("#typing_on").addClass("class2");
  event.preventDefault();
});

<textarea id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5">
</textarea>
<div id="typing_on" class="">Class2</div>
.class1 {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.class2 {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```